# how to importing json file to elasticsearch using python

Tags: python

I have a json file which contains multiple id's and I want it to import that file to elasicsearch in kibana using python and there should be different index for different id. Please tell me how can i do that.

```py
import json   
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch  
    es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
i = 0  
with open('js.json') as raw_data:  
    json_docs = json.load(raw_data)  
    for json_doc in json_docs:  
            i = i + 1  
            es.index(index='elasticsearch_index',doc_type='raw_data', id=i, body=json.dumps(json_doc))
```

This is my code please help me to in it.

Comment: Did you read [ask] and research for e.g. "elasticsearch add document to index python" ? I found the tutorial [How to Index Elasticsearch Documents Using the Python Client Library | ObjectRocket](https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/how-to-index-elasticsearch-documents-using-the-python-client-library), does this help?

Comment: Please post your JSON file as example, the mapping of different indexes to ids and the [example] you tried using Python. Currently your question is not clear enough and missing requirements of Stackoverflow. When you [edit] the question with missing information we can help you.